# Custom WordPress New User E-Mail from Template

Tags: html, wordpress, email

From a custom function to register users, I inserted this function to generate and overwrite the WordPress system email for new user notification.

```php
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
      global $wpcargo;
        $user_url = stripslashes( $user->user_url );
        $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
        $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
        $user_firstname = stripslashes( $user->user_firstname );
        $user_last_name = stripslashes( $user->user_last_name );
        $user_pass = stripslashes( $user->user_pass );
        $message = file_get_contents('../email/mail-template.php');
        $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] Welcome.', $blogname );
        $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message; 
        return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );
```

Emails are being sent but I cannot get user data printed in the PHP / HTML file.

```
<p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:12px;"><b>Name</b>: <?php $user_firstname; ?></p>
```

I'm wrong with the code, any suggestions?

Comment: `<?php echo $user_firstname; ?>` OR `<?= $user_firstname; ?>`

Comment: looking into code gives idea only subject, headers and message variables are getting returned  by function and message does not suppose to contain anything related with user information.
I think you need to take another variable $wp_new_user_notification_email['user_firstname']  = $user_firstname; to pass this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `locate_template` for the email contents and `output buffering` rather than `file_get_contents` - also as @Zak pointed out, you have to `echo` your output otherwise it won't show up.

```php
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    global $wpcargo;
    $user_url = stripslashes( $user->user_url );
    $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
    $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    $user_firstname = stripslashes( $user->user_firstname );
    $user_last_name = stripslashes( $user->user_last_name );
    $user_pass = stripslashes( $user->user_pass );
    ob_start();
    include( locate_template( '/email/mail-template.php' ); // This path may vary depending on your setup.
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = ob_get_clean();
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] Welcome.', $blogname );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );
```

Within your template you want to make sure you echo and `esc_html()` for anything that is being outputted.

```php
<?php echo esc_html( $user_firstname ); ?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks! Perfect!
It works ... now I just have to know how to view the user password and not its hash encoding :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the system still does not allow me to vote in this way.
I take this opportunity to ask you for another help.
The password that is printed in the email of the user who registers is in hash.
Is there a way to print the password in plaintext?

Comment: That would really be a different question.  You'd have to pass the plaintext password from the _POST entry to some kind of transient, since the pw is hashed right away.